# Convert spanned to uppercase

Tags: android

I have a `Spanned` instance that was returned by `Html.fromHtml()`, and I would like to convert the text to uppercase. Unlike `String` the other Android `CharSequence` implementations do not have a `toUpperCase()` method. Obviously calling `toString()` results in all of the links and other formatting being lost.

Comment: see TextUtils.copySpansFrom method

Comment: Thank you. That's a more elegant way of doing it than I had come up with.

Comment: btw replace doesn't preserve spans,  so your solution is not working (at least in v2.2)

Comment: see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html#replace(int, int, java.lang.CharSequence) "If source is Spanned, the spans from it are preserved into the Editable. Existing spans within the Editable that entirely cover the replaced range are retained, **but any that were strictly within the range that was replaced are removed.**"

Comment: That explains why it continued to work for me. All my strings had spans that covered the whole thing. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a new string from the original CharSequence, up case it, and reapply all the original spans to it. This worked for me:

```
public static Spanned csToUpperCase(@NonNull Spanned s) {
    Object[] spans = s.getSpans(0,
            s.length(), Object.class);
    SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(s.toString().toUpperCase());

    // reapply the spans to the now uppercase string
    for (Object span : spans) {
        spannableString.setSpan(span,
                s.getSpanStart(span),
                s.getSpanEnd(span),
                0);
    }

    return spannableString;
}
```

Comment: Only using .toUpperCase() and reapplying spans is not good enough. If you have characters like ß the span length will be wrong. As ß turns into SS when uppercased.
See my answer below for a better solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63935962/9017295

Answer (score 3):

Only using `.toUpperCase()` and reapplying spans is not good enough. If you have characters like `ß` the span length will be wrong. As `ß` turns into `SS` when uppercased.

There might be some language that turns several chars into one when uppercased, but I am not aware of an example. We can avoid that entirely anyway by uppercasing the chars one by one.

Here's a simple solution that should handle most edge cases:

```
private fun toUpperCase(locale: Locale, source: CharSequence, copySpans: Boolean): CharSequence{
    if(!copySpans) return source.toString().toUpperCase(locale)
    val upcased: List<String> = source.map { c ->
       c.toString().toUpperCase(locale)
    }
    val spanned = source as Spanned
    val spans: Array<Any> = source.getSpans(0, source.length, Any::class.java)
    val sb = SpannableStringBuilder(upcased.joinToString(""))
    for(span in spans){
        val spanStart = spanned.getSpanStart(span)
        val spanEnd = spanned.getSpanEnd(span)
        val upcasedEndLength: Int = upcased.slice(spanStart until spanEnd).fold(0){ a,b -> a+b.length}
        val upcasedStartLength: Int = if(spanStart == 0) 0 else upcased.slice(0 until spanStart).fold(0){ a,b -> a+b.length}
        val destStart = upcasedStartLength
        val destEnd = destStart + upcasedEndLength

        val flags = spanned.getSpanFlags(span)
        sb.setSpan(span,destStart,destEnd,flags)
    }
    return sb
}
```

This is not necessary in SDK29 btw, as the AllCapsTransformationMethod there handles spans perfectly.
You could import `com.ibm.icu:icu4j:67.1` and use the needed methods from there, it is equal to the one in SDK29, but it will increase the size of your app a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone out there is still looking for this. I've found a nice solution...
You have a `Span` called `ReplacementSpan` which has one method that give you the CharSequence needed

```
abstract void draw(Canvas canvas, CharSequence text, int start, int end, float x, int top, int y, int bottom, Paint paint)
```

Inherit that class and set your `Span` to that. You'll have full control of what is going on with the string. Here's an example:

```
class HeadingSpan : ReplacementSpan() {

    override fun getSize(paint: Paint, text: CharSequence?, start: Int, end: Int, fm: Paint.FontMetricsInt?): Int =
            paint.measureText(text, start, end).roundToInt()

    override fun draw(canvas: Canvas, text: CharSequence?, start: Int, end: Int, x: Float, top: Int, y: Int, bottom: Int, paint: Paint) {
        canvas.drawText(text.toString().toUpperCase(), start, end, x, y.toFloat(), paint)
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

In Html.fromHtml() method you will sending the string, so you can convert that string to upper case and the get the span from Html.fromHtml


Example

 Html.fromHtml(lSampleString..toUpperCase();